# Dagger 2 doesn't provide my class as singleton, why?

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have a class:

```
public class MyFactory {
    public MyFactory() {
    }

}
```

My Dagger module:

```
@Module
public class MyModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public MyFactory provideMyFactory() {
        return new MyFactory();
    }
}
```

My component:

```
@Singleton
@MyScope
@Component(modules = MyModule.class)
public interface MyComponent {
    MyFactory getMyFactory();
}
```

My Scope:

```
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
public @interface MyScope {
}
```

I expect `MyFactory` instance being provided by Dagger2 is a singleton however, it is not. I tried to call following code in **two** places of my project:

```
MyFactory factory = DaggerMyComponent.builder()
                .build()
                .getMyFactory();
Logcat.d("tag", "factory = " + factory);
```

My log shows me :

```
factory = :com.my.app.MyFactory@eaa9330
factory = :com.my.app.MyFactory@8bd552e
```

As you can see, they are two instances. So, **My questions are**:

**Question 1.** In above case, why Dagger doesn't provide `MyFactory` as a singleton??

**Question 2.** With my above code, does everytime calling `DaggerMyComponent.builder().build();` create a new instance of `MyComponent`?

**Question 3.** Dagger also allow developer's class instance to be injectable by place a `@Inject` annotation in constructor **without bothering having the module**:

```
public class MyFactory {
    @Inject
    public MyFactory() {
    }
}
```

developer can use it just by `@Inject MyFactory factory;`
In this case, how to make `MyFactory` singleton with Dagger 2?

Comment: Because you're creating a new component each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scopes are *per component*. If you create multiple components then you create multiple objects. `@Singleton` is no exception.

```
// same component
DaggerMyComponent firstComponent = DaggerMyComponent.builder().build();

firstComponent.getMyFactory() == firstComponent.getMyFactory(); // true


// second component
DaggerMyComponent secondComponent = DaggerMyComponent.builder().build();

firstComponent.getMyFactory() == secondComponent.getMyFactory(); // false
```

You will have to *keep* the component instances and *reuse* them, or you will always create new references. E.g. A common way is to place the `@Singleton AppComponent` within your `Application` and grab it from there when needed.

> In this case, how to make MyFactory singleton with Dagger 2?

With constructor injection you just add the scope to the top of the class.

```
@Singleton // place scope _on_ the class
public class MyFactory {
  @Inject
  public MyFactory() {
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean everytime I call `DaggerMyComponent.builder().build();` it creates a new instance of `MyComponent`? If so, is there a way to make component singleton?

Comment: What about my question 3?

Comment: @Leem.fin Yes, it will always recreate the component with everything in it. There is no "true" singleton with Dagger. You should keep your Singleton scoped component in your Application and reuse it from there. I'd advise against storing it in a static variable. I updated the answer to reflect the question